# Showing a custom field in front-end without a form

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, custom-field

I have a custom field called time which has the below coding.

```
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldTime extends JFormFieldList{

  protected $type = 'time';

  public function getOptions($id='') {
    //Do the process and return
    return $options;
  }
}
```

The above works perfect at back-end because I have XML forms for each views.

My question now is how to show the field in the front-end where I don't have XML forms because of custom designs.

I tried the below in my edit.php (front-end)

```
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/mylib/fields/time.php';
$timefield = JFormHelper::loadFieldType('time', false);
$timeslots=$timefield->getOptions();
```

The above code gives all the options.  Is there a simple way to convert this to a select list box.  I know the hard way is to loop through and form the select box.  Just want to know is there any simpler way like JHTML::...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution as simple as below.

```
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');

require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/mylib/fields/time.php';

$timefield = JFormHelper::loadFieldType('time', false);
$timeslots=$timefield->getOptions();

echo JHtmlSelect::genericlist($timeslots, "note_start_time",null,'value','text',$start_time)
```

It works cool.